# Phonegap AJAX URL shows Status 404 on android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in `Phonegap/Cordova`. I am facing a problem for 2 days that I cannot able to call `AJAX` (URL) on my mobile device. I have tried every thing, read every forum but nothing works. On mobile it always show me '`Status 404`'. It works perfectly on Ripple Emulator. Even I use promise.js as I read on many forums. Below is the code snippet:

```
 var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pageData;

        $('#test-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formVal1 = $('#formVal1').val().trim();
            var formVal2 = $('#formVal2').val().trim();

            if (formVal1 != '' && formVal2 != '')    {
                // B-> Here you define its functions and its payload
                var mdnAPI = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search.json';
                /*var payload = {
                    'formVal1' : formVal1,
                    'formVal2' : formVal2
                };*/
                var payload = {
                    'topic' : 'js',
                    'q'     : 'Promise'
                }

                var callback = {
                    success : function(data) {
                    console.log(1, 'success', JSON.parse(data));
                    /* $.mobile.changePage("#application-status", {
                        respData: JSON.parse(data),
                        transition: "flip"
                     }); */
                  },
                  error : function(data) {
                     console.log(2, 'error', JSON.parse(data));
                  }
                };

                $.support.cors=true;
                // Executes the method call
                $http(mdnAPI)
                    .post(payload)
                    .then(callback.success)
                    .catch(callback.error);
            }
            return false;       //this is must
        });
    }
  }
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.project.sample.buildingpermit" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

`Config.xml`:

```
  <access origin="*" />
  <access origin="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search.json" />
```

`index.html`:

```
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
        // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!
        alert('I am here ');
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.support.cors=true;
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

Note: I Execute commands:

1) cordova platform version android shows: Installed platforms: android 4.0.2

2) phonegap -v shows:   5.0.0-0.28.1

Can any one provide me the solution I am stuck with this problem for last 2 days?
I also turned on the Mobile Internet on my android device but nothing works. First, i use my local network IP in URL now, I deployed on Internet but still not works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed and configured the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist ? (should be added automatically when creating project with cordova 5)

Comment: Yes, I installed cordova-plugin-whitelist.

Comment: And have you fully configured it (in config.xml and in the html file?)

Comment: Check this link and the plugin doc : http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5

Comment: Yes, config.xml is attached in above. Please review that it fulfills the white-list requirement.

Comment: Can you tell me how it is fully configured in Html and config.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure about your double access origin in config.xml, access origin="*" says you accept any origin, so no other line should be needed. The second part of the configuration is you have to add a meta tag meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" in each html file to configure what access the file should be granted. Please see the link I provided in previous comment for more info.

Comment: But never mind, cross origin issues should not show a 404 error. Are you sure the URL you are targetting with the ajax call is reachable from the device you're running the app in? (same network... or if in emulator, is network enabled...)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check the 'content-security-Policy'. Yes, the url is basically a servlet which returns a JSON using a POST request. I log the url and its the same which I tested in Chrome 'PostMan' plugin.

Comment: When I add the http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" it shows me the same error as mentioned in your provided URL i.e. "Refused to connect to 'http://?????????formVal1=1&formVal2=2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback"

Comment: I am using 4g and I checked using 'navigator.connection.type' it shows 4G and the url is hosted on internet so, there is no question regarding same network now. Am I right?

Comment: sure you're right. Have you checked that the url is reachable via a browser in your device?

Comment: Yes, the URL is reachable using mobile browser. I checked

Comment: Can you please tell me whether it check the given URL on internet or local area network because it is currently host over internet. I think it check on local area network that's why its shows 404. Please confirm!

Comment: Cordova/Phonegap works with local and internet urls. To be sure if you have a issue with the security, if you don't understand how to properly configure the content-security-policy, you can try to remove the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin and add instead cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist (it will work like with older versions of cordova and only check access origin="*" in config.xml) if it works, I'll try to spend more time to write an answer and explain how to configure CSP

Comment: One more thing, I am using 'promise.js' which is receiving a 'json' response. I read somewhere to access cross domain should use 'jsonp' instead of 'json'. Does it make sense or should I change it to 'jsonp' to test or it is useless to test using 'jsonp'?

Comment: THANKS Man. You made my day :) It works by removing 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' plugin and add 'cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist'. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82041/discussion-between-adeel-asghar-and-quickfix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After strenuous effort of 2 days and with the help of @QuickFix who continuously responded above, the issue has been solved.

Fix:

- Remove 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' plugin.
- Add 'cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist' plugin.